# Limit elements to show based width in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, server-side-rendering

I want to limit the number of elements (files) shown based on the client's width in my Next project. I'm using the useEffect hook and adding an event listener for the resize. It is responsive. For that, I'm also using grid auto-fill for this. The problem is that when I start the page or refresh it this doesn't work correctly. Here's the code:

```js
 const files = useSelector((state:RootState)=>state.files);

  const [limitFilesBasedWidth, setLimitFilesBasedWidth] = useState(0);
  const gridRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updateLimitFilesBasedWidth = () => {
      if (gridRef.current && files.length > 0) {
        const containerWidth = gridRef.current.offsetWidth;
        const fileWidth = getFileWidth();

        console.log("FILE WIDTH:",fileWidth, containerWidth, Math.floor(containerWidth / fileWidth), "hola")

        let newLimit = Math.floor(containerWidth / fileWidth);
        if (newLimit > 4){ 
          newLimit = 4
        }
        setLimitFilesBasedWidth(newLimit);
      }
    };

    // Call the function once on component mount
    updateLimitFilesBasedWidth();

    // Recalculate the limit whenever the window is resized
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateLimitFilesBasedWidth);

    // Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateLimitFilesBasedWidth);
    };
  }, [files]);
const getFileWidth = () => {
    const suggestedFileElement = document.querySelector('.individual-file-container');
    if (suggestedFileElement) {
      return suggestedFileElement.clientWidth;
    }
    return 200; // Default width if element not found
  };

  // Right click
  const [contextMenu, setContextMenu] = useState(initialContextMenu);

  const handleSuggestedFileContextMenu = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement,globalThis.MouseEvent>) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const { pageX, pageY } = e;
    setContextMenu((prevContextState) => {
        return prevContextState.map((menu) => {
            if (menu.section === "suggested_file") {
                return {...menu, show: true, x: pageX, y: pageY };
            }
            return menu;
        });
    });
  };

  const closeCurrentContextMenu = () => setContextMenu(initialContextMenu);

  const [changingName, setChangingName] = useState(false);

  const changeFileNameState = (bool:boolean) => {
    setChangingName(bool);
  }

  return (
    <div className={`suggested-file-gallery ${space_grotesk.className} ml-[31px] mr-[33px] mb-[20px]`}>
      {contextMenu.find((section) => section.section === "suggested_file")?.show && 
      <SuggestedFileContextMenu
      x={contextMenu.find((section) => section.section === "suggested_file")?.x ?? 0} 
      y={contextMenu.find((section) => section.section === "suggested_file")?.y ?? 0} 
      changeFileName={changeFileNameState}
      closeCurrentContextMenu={closeCurrentContextMenu}
      />}
      {files.length === 0 ? 
          <></>
        : 
        <>
          <section className="flex items-center text-secondarytxt mt-[14px] mb-[10px]">
            Suggested
          </section>
          <div ref={gridRef} className="w-full grid grid-cols-suggested-files 2xl:grid-cols-suggested-uw-files  gap-3 auto-rows-[181px]">
            {files.slice(0, limitFilesBasedWidth).map((file,index)=>{
              return <SuggestedFile 
                      key={index} 
                      id={file.id}
                      file={file}
                      changingName={changingName}
                      changeFileNameState={changeFileNameState}
                      handleSuggestedFileContextMenu={handleSuggestedFileContextMenu}/>;
            })}
          </div>
        </>}
    </div>
  );
```

```json
gridTemplateColumns: {
        // Complex site-specific column configuration
        'suggested-files': 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(256px,1fr))',
        'suggested-uw-files': 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(256px,1fr))',
      }
```

Here's what happens when I refresh:
[image: BUG]

They are supposed to be just two of them. Also, it prints that the initial fileWidth is 203px always.

[image: SOLVED]

This is visually solved by just resizing or opening and closing the dev tools. I don't know if the problem is with my grid class, with my logic, or Next's SSR.